# Visual Studio error while trying to run project

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have the following scenario:

- Visual Studio 2010 solution with one WPF-project, output file is "Tool.exe"
- Eclipse Shared Library project, output file is "Tool.dll"

I place the dll in the same folder as the exe and then I try to debug using Visual Studio; but I get the following error:

> Error while trying to run project: Could not load file or assembly 'Tool' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.

I have managed to find a solution to the problem, **rename** the dll, apparently the exe and dll cannot have the same name. My question is, why is this error occuring in the first place? Why does the name of the dll affect Visual Studio? The error occurs before even trying to pinvoke the dll. If I run my application without Visual Studio it works perfectly, but I want to be able to debug it of course.

Right now renaming the dll is plan B, but before I do that I would like to know if there is anything else I can do to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your project code you missing some assembly file. to know which assembly file is missing in your code you expand the reference option in the solution explorer and the missing file is colored with error mark. to add this file just write click on the reference and add the references. you can add the references from computer, form .net or used project as reference for your project.

Comment: do one thing "go to the build and click clean solutions.It worked for me."

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I am not missing an assembly, if I was the project would not even build. As I wrote, it works perfectly if I double click the exe without involving Visual Studio.

Answer (score -2):

I found  simple steps to solve this error.

1- change your windows.

2- install Symantec Endpoint Protection Client 12.1.6318.6100 x32 or x64 bit.

You can geting it software(32 bit) from link: (ftp://192.168.168.215/Public/Antivirus/Symantec/Symantec Endpoint Protection Client 12.1.6318.6100 x86.rar)

drag and drop it to your software(IE ,....) to work.

3- install all driver on your computer.

4- install Visual studio.

End